# What does this PHP syntax mean? Can't find any information in the docs

Tags: php

```
function get( $str ){
    $matches = $this->xml->xpath("/conf/item [@name= \"$str\"]");
    if (count($matches)) {
    $this->lastmatch = $matches[0];
    return (string) $matches[0];
}
```

I can't find any information about what the last line of this code does.

What does this **(string) $matches[0]** piece do?

As I can guess, it returns the zero element of the array as a string. But I didn't find any mention about this syntax in the docs.

Am I right?

And it will be great if you provide me with a link where I can read about this.

Comment: type juggling variable convert to string http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: It returns the first element of the `$matches` array, type-cast as a string. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Try to `var_dump($matches)` and see what it's returning. Yes array, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
It is called type juggling, because php does not have explicit types.

You can use the following type castings:

> (int), (integer) - cast to integer
>   (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
>   (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
>   (string) - cast to string
>   (array) - cast to array
>   (object) - cast to object
>   (unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)